# gwt cell table dynamic columns - sorting

Tags: gwt, dynamic, celltable, dynamic-columns

You can represent your "rows" as `List<String>` instances, you have to change your parameterization from String to List in your Grid, Column and data provider; and of course you have to call updateRowData with a `List<List<String>>`, not a `List<String>`.

You also need one Column instance per column, taking the value out of the List by index:

```java
   class IndexedColumn extends Column<List<String>, String> {

       private final int index;

       public IndexedColumn(int index) {
           super(new EditTextCell());
           this.index = index;
       }

       @Override
       public String getValue(List<String> object) {
           return object.get(this.index);
       }

   }
```

How do i add sorting to this example. I tried a `ListHandler` but not sure how to compare `List<String>`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the below link - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752633/programatic-celltable-sort-in-gwt-not-working/13767108#13767108

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the data grid code

```java
indexedColumn.setSortable(true);
sortHandler.setComparator((Column<T, ?>) indexedColumn, (Comparator<T>) indexedColumn.getComparator(true));
```

Here is the actual class

```java
    public class IndexedColumn extends Column<List<String>, String>
{
   private Comparator<List<String>> forwardComparator;
   private Comparator<List<String>> reverseComparator;
   private final int index;

   public IndexedColumn(int index)
   {
      super(new TextCell());
      this.index = index;
   }

   @Override
   public String getValue(List<String> object)
   {
      return object.get(index);
   }

   public Comparator<List<String>> getComparator(final boolean reverse)
   {
      if (!reverse && forwardComparator != null)
      {
         return forwardComparator;
      }
      if (reverse && reverseComparator != null)
      {
         return reverseComparator;
      }
      Comparator<List<String>> comparator = new Comparator<List<String>>()
      {
         public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2)
         {
            if (o1 == null && o2 == null)
            {
               return 0;
            }
            else if (o1 == null)
            {
               return reverse ? 1 : -1;
            }
            else if (o2 == null)
            {
               return reverse ? -1 : 1;
            }

            // Compare the column value.
            String c1 = getValue(o1);
            String c2 = getValue(o2);
            if (c1 == null && c2 == null)
            {
               return 0;
            }
            else if (c1 == null)
            {
               return reverse ? 1 : -1;
            }
            else if (c2 == null)
            {
               return reverse ? -1 : 1;
            }
            int comparison = ((String) c1).compareTo(c2);
            return reverse ? -comparison : comparison;
         }
      };

      if (reverse)
      {
         reverseComparator = comparator;
      }
      else
      {
         forwardComparator = comparator;
      }
      return comparator;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `ListHandler` to each column you want to sort separately. Kind of like this:

You'll have to add a getter method to `IndexedColumn` for the `index`:

```java
class IndexedColumn extends Column<List<String>, String> {

    private final int index;

    public IndexedColumn(int index) {
        super(new EditTextCell());
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(List<String> object) {
        return object.get(this.index);
    }

    public int getIndex(){
        return index;
    }

}
```

Then you'll need to add a `ListHandler` to the `CellTable`:

```java
ListHandler<List<String>> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<List<String>>(list);
    columnSortHandler.setComparator(columnName, new Comparator<List<String>>() {

        public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
          if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
          }

          // Compare the column.
          if (o1 != null) {
            int index = columnName.getIndex();
            return (o2 != null) ? o1.get(index).compareTo(o2.get(index)) : 1;
          }
          return -1;
        }
    });
table.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);
```

In the example above `list` is the `List<List<String>>` object. The `columnName` is the `Column` object. You'll have to do this for every column you want to sort.

Don't forget to also call `.setSortable(true)` on each of the columns that you will sort.

A good basic example of column sorting can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable#columnSorting). The code above is based on this example but I used your `index` in `IndexedColumn` in order to get the proper `String` for the column to do the comparison.